# Unicode characters are not recognized in java

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

I have created a java code that will store an uploaded text document. Then I return the text in that file. All the text are in "sinhala" language. UTF-8 encoded text

```
        streamReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath)), "utf8" /*Here I have tried 'UTF-8', 'utf-8'*/);
        br = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        PrintStream printStream= new PrintStream(f);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            .....
        }
```

The output is directly sent to jsp page, there it's shown as  '????????????????????????????????'.

Windows 8.1, tomcat and java version 7. I have tested jsp with sinhala characters, they are working.
I have added UTF-8, as content type.

I have tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733584/to-read-unicode-character-in-java), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630609/reading-unicode-character-in-java), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979932/read-unicode-text-files-with-java) too.

Comment: I would try setting UTF-8 for the output i.e. PrintStream as well.

Comment: Unicode characters certainly *are* recognized in Java, but your Java program can read, manipulate, or output them incorrectly if you so choose.  Also, whatever mechanism you are using to examine the result might do the wrong thing with your program's output.  Your code fragment looks a bit suspicious, but you haven't given us a complete example to work with, so we can't say much.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, `PrintStream`s and other `OutputStream`s don't *have* an encoding associated with them.  That is what I find most suspicious, in fact.  `OutputStream`s are for writing binary data; for character data one should use a `Writer`.

Comment: You need to show us the JSP, and to show how the output is sent directly to it. Also make sure that the font used in your web page is able to show those "sinhala" characters.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was thinking PrintWriter so your comment helped me come up with an answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSP` must provide the specified encoding as `UTF-8` well as **all** the `InputStream/Writer` and `OutputStream/Writers` having the `UTF-8` character set explicitly provided.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the encoding for a Writer you can do

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new InputStreamWriter(f, "UTF-8"));
```

You can use a PrintWriter instead or a PrintStream as it has the same methods.

Comment: and the `JSP/HTML` headers need to specify `UTF-8` as well for this to be a complete solution. `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the correct encoding of the HTTP response.

If you insert the text in JSP, set the JSP encoding at the top of the .jsp file (see also [UTF-8 encoding in JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723339/utf-8-encoding-in-jsp-page)):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
...
<c:out value="${myDocumentTextInUnicode}"/>
```

If generating the response in a servlet, set the encoding there:

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    out.println(line);
}
```