# Scanner difficulties with different escape characters

Tags: java, escaping, java.util.scanner, java-io

First off let me start by saying that I know I'm not the only one who has experienced this issue and I spent the last couple of hours to research how to fix it. Sadly, I can't get my scanner to work. I'm new to java so I don't understand more complicated explanations that some answers have in different questions.

Here is a rundown:
I'm trying to read out of a file which contains escape characters of cards. Here is a short version: (Numbers 2 and 3 of 4 different card faces)

```
\u26602,2 
\u26652,2 
\u26662,2 
\u26632,2 
\u26603,3 
\u26653,3 
\u26663,3
\u26633,3
```

This is the format: (suit)(face),(value).  an example:

- \u2663 = suit
- 3 = face
- 3 = value

This is the code I'm using for reading it:

```
File file = new File("Cards.txt");
try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] temp = line.split(",");
        cards.add(new Card(temp[0], Integer.parseInt(temp[1])));
    }
    scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the ArrayList cards should have 52 cards after this containing a name (suit and face) and a value. When i try to print the name this is the output:

```
\u26633
```

While it should be:

```
♣3
```

Can anyone give me pointers towards a solution? I really need this issue resolved. I don't want you to write my code for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply store directly the suit characters into your files `Cards.txt` using UTF-8 as character encoding instead of the corresponding unicode character format that is only understood by java such that when it is read from your file it is read as the `String` "`\u2660`" not as the corresponding unicode character.

Its content would then be something like:

```
♠2,2
...
```

---

Another way could be to use [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(String input)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava-java.lang.String-) to unescape your unicode character.

The code change would then be:

```
cards.add(new Card(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(temp[0]), Integer.parseInt(temp[1])));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never thought about just putting the character itself in the text file and saving it with UTF-8 encoding! It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to save your file with `UTF-8` encoding and then read the file using the same encoding.

> ♥,1
>
> ♥,2
>
> ♥,3

Here is the code snippet:

```
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream("Cards.txt"), "UTF-8"));

String input = null;
while (null != (input = buff.readLine())) {
    System.out.println(input);
    String[] temp = input.split(",");
    cards.add(new Card(temp[0], Integer.parseInt(temp[1])));
}

buff.close();
```

Also, you need to make sure that your console is enabled to support `UTF-8`. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18733665/2004685) answer to read more about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question. I already found Nicolas Filotto's answer to work.